# How can I check if a URI displayed by java.awt.Desktop is blank or not

Tags: java, web, uri

I want to write a program that opens different URI's while changing a parameter. How can I check if the loaded page is blank or has data?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, since Desktop.browse(...) opens the systems default browser, which will be an external program. But you can use the URL class to open a connection to your URLs, and check if the underlying inputstream contains data (InputStream.available()).

Comment: Does this work too if the url is .aspx and the pdf is displayed using type="application/pdf"?

Comment: Yes, calling such a url would result in a download of the media behind it. You dont need to download the media, but just check, if there are bytes in the stream available.